# Cannot find snapshot for id: -4123461672748341163-AndroidStudio

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Android Studio error while rebuilding the project.
any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Please Post the BuildToolVersion and gradle version. Thanks

Comment: Not constructive

Answer (score 0):

Look in the sdk Manager what is your highest Android sdk Build-tools version, & copy this version number in ur project's build.gradle file, in the android/buildToolsVersion property.

Change Gradle Version -

/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

Edit the distributionUrl line and set it too:

distributionUrl=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-all.zip

Rebuild your project.